# Sending multiple mails java with attachments cause them to arrive out of order

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am using javamail api to send messages with attachments-attachments and messages are in separate folder and even though I create and send messages in a specific order, they arrive on gmail in a different order. What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: Mail arrival order is not guaranteed regardless of the tech you use.

Comment: You can try to use delivery confirmation and send next message after current is delivered. But it may take unpredictable amount of time. Also may not work with some mail client. So no good solution for you.

Comment: Many possible causes.The speed of connections to the mail server or the server prioritising their processing in a way out of your control. If order is important, try sending with a delay between them and increase the delay until they get ordered.

Comment: So there is no way to guarantee that emails will arrive at particular order? Any source of info on that matter?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that was my thought initially but essentially you do end up using magic numbers through trial and error, right?

Comment: @CPerkins :) So categorically unreserved verdict. I don't know why, but every time I sent an email yesterday, it was received before the mail I'm sending today. (long gone the open-relay era in mailing - today, one contacts directly the destination mail server)

Comment: @JimRod "end up using magic numbers through trial and error". And a bit worse than that: your magic numbers today may fail tomorrow. :) Well, such is the life we are living: imperfect or even faulty; on the plus side, unpredictability makes it somehow interesting, less boring and perhaps worth living. ;)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi is there any form of documentation online explaining why order is not guaranteed?

Comment: @JimRod "any form of documentation online" I really don't know

Comment: Order is not guaranteed *because there's no explicit guarantee of ordering*. Unpredictable order is the general case.

Comment: How are you determining what order the messages are arriving in?  Most mailers will sort the messages and display them in order by date/time sent.

Comment: @BillShannon To be fair I was checking the order by seeing the order of messages in the outbox (array containing all the messages) and then the inbox and check if the order in which they were sent was the same with the order in which they arrived

Comment: You're looking at the `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` folder, right?  If Gmail is putting the messages in that folder in the order you're sending them, but not putting them in the Inbox folder in the same order, then that's an issue for Gmail, but it probably comes back to the original point in that delivery order is never guaranteed.